# Is it possible to center a div that already has float: left; set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

currently I'm trying to create a dock (similar to the iOS dock) for my website, my full code is

```js
function addPrevClass(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (target.getAttribute('src')) { // check if it is img
    var li = target.parentNode.parentNode;
    var prevLi = li.previousElementSibling;
    if (prevLi) {
      prevLi.className = 'prev';
    }

    target.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      prevLi.removeAttribute('class');
    }, false);
  }
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
  document.getElementById("dock").addEventListener('mouseover', addPrevClass, false);
}
```

```css
li {
  float: left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
#dock li img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 2px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.7, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)));
  /* reflection is supported by webkit only */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
#dock li:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  margin: 0 2em;
}
#dock li:hover + li img,
#dock li.prev img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  margin: 0 1.5em;
}
#dock-container ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="dock-container">
  <div id="dock">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="http://android.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://palm.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://android.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://palm.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://android.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://palm.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://android.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="base"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But my problem here is that my dock is not centered on the website, and when i try to take the float: left; off, my dock becomes vertical, how would i center the dock and still keep it horizontal? any ideas?

Comment: It is possible to center things both vertically and horizontally. Can you be more specific as to whether you want horizontal or vertical centering?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally centering a <ul> navbar that contains floated li elements in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487328/horizontally-centering-a-ul-navbar-that-contains-floated-li-elements-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

Change float:left to display: inline; or display: inline-block for li, depending on your needs:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This is the normal approach for centering horizontal lists in css. Beware that  you will get a space between each element in the list when using display: inline. (https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: changing the li to display: inline; makes my dock vertical, maybe something else in the css file is affecting it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I wasn't sure if it would matter between inline or inline block, but it does indeed.

Comment: I just did it in your code sample and it worked.  If that's not happening in your full app you may have something else wrong, but in the code you posted it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the display:table; property and set margin:auto; if i understood your trouble. This way , ul can shrink on its content and still behave as a block element.

```js
function addPrevClass(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (target.getAttribute('src')) { // check if it is img
    var li = target.parentNode.parentNode;
    var prevLi = li.previousElementSibling;
    if (prevLi) {
      prevLi.className = 'prev';
    }

    target.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      prevLi.removeAttribute('class');
    }, false);
  }
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
  document.getElementById("dock").addEventListener('mouseover', addPrevClass, false);
}
```

```css
li {
  float: left;
}
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  /*margin: 0;*/
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
#dock li img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 2px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.7, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)));
  /* reflection is supported by webkit only */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
#dock li:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  margin: 0 2em;
}
#dock li:hover + li img,
#dock li.prev img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  margin: 0 1.5em;
}
#dock-container ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="dock-container">
  <div id="dock">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="http://android.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://palm.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://android.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://palm.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://android.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://palm.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://android.com">
          <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1330446/demo/dock/images/dock-icons/palm.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="base"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `float: left` to avoid the space between each list item you can use:

```
#dock {
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css3 can save you. Add the following and try

```
#dock{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```